# Wine + Itunes Compatibility (Arch Linux)

Tags: linux, itunes, archlinux, wine, winexe

I have WINE installed and configured correctly (I believe).

When I download "iTunes64Setup.exe", I am greeted with:

`"This iTunes installer is intended for 32-bit versions of Windows. Please download and install the 64-bit iTunes installer instead."`

Now, when I download"iTunesSetup.exe" (the 32 bit version), I get:

`"This iTunes installer is intended for 64-bit versions of Windows. Please download and install the 32-bit iTunes installer instead."`

I'm runnning Arch Linux (Manjaro 3.10.25)

`wine --version` returns
`wine-1.7.9`

As we speak, I am updating to WINE 1.7.10 via Pacman,  though I've seen people using <1.7.9 with iTunes.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow** unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su]

Comment: Alright. Appreciate the comment.

Comment: you can click the flag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288688/wine-itunes-compatibility-arch-linux# and ask moderator to move your question. Good luck.